# error in flask-peewee Admin User creation

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, orm, peewee

Database example.db is created but generates error !!!

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_testing.py", line 39, in  admin.save()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Envs\surveyApp\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2405, in save
    new_pk = insert.execute()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Envs\surveyApp\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1721, in execute
    return self.database.last_insert_id(self._execute(), self.model_class)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Envs\surveyApp\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1420, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Envs\surveyApp\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1824, in execute_sql
    res = cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.IntegrityError: column email is not unique

## Code

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask_peewee.admin import Admin
from flask_peewee.auth import Auth
from flask_peewee.db import Database
from peewee import *

# configure our database
DATABASE = {
    'name': 'example.db',
    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
}
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'ssshhhh'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# instantiate the db wrapper
db = Database(app)

# create an Auth object for use with our flask app and database wrapper
auth = Auth(app, db)
admin = Admin(app, auth)

class Note(db.Model):
    message = TextField()
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

admin.register(Note)
admin.setup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth.User.create_table(fail_silently=True)
    Note.create_table(fail_silently=True)

    admin = auth.User(username='admin', email='aoeu@gmail.com', admin=True, active=True)
    admin.set_password('admin')
    admin.save()
    app.run()
```

## using example from

http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#setting-up-a-simple-base-template

Answer (score 0):

Database was already created, deleting previous database solved it